# Angular-Datepicker does not work when there is no space between datepicker and adjacent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I'd like to know the reason why it is not working? Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/summersoldier/pen/dWzyKa) . I tried to use two bootstrap inputs one after another each of datepicker type and added a few more elements in the bottom, they do not work straight out as they should. I'd like to know the reasons deep down.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Date-Picker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/master/src/css/angular-datepicker.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/master/src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container">

      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <!-- This is the test template that eill be loaded into view -->
        <h1>Test Template</h1>

        <br><br>
        <div class="well text-center">
          {{date}}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">

            <!-- Start Date -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <input ng-model="date" type="text"
                  placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control"/>
              </datepicker>
            </div>

            <!-- Uncomment to make it work -->
            <!--<br>-->
            <!-- End Date -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <datepicker date-format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <input ng-model="date" type="text"
                  placeholder="End Date" class="form-control"/>
              </datepicker>
            </div>

            <!-- Uncomment to make it work -->
            <!--<br>-->
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="i in list">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">
                {{i}}
              </label>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['720kb.datepicker']);

      /**
      * CONTROLLER
      * ========================================
      */
      app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Rj";
        $scope.list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
      }]);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to debug it with your browser's element inspector :O, your checkbox div is overlaping the picker

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWybMR

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elements overlap so the events don't trigger properly

Set the following css:

```
.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

demo:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyjVw

another solution will be to wrap your inputs in .row divs

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyjYwv

or add `.clearfix` to the `.form-group` divs

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmKwoN

Comment: If he doesn't want that margins between elements, he should style each element class, hmmm

Comment: Thanks for explaining y'all!, dummy me I thought there'd be some js based reason!